# How do I create a glass pane roof?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've seen that mobs can be trapped within glass pane fairly easily, and would love to make a nice green house with a glass roof to let sunlight in during the day.  But I can't seem to cajole my glass pane to take any shape other than the T-intersection shape that allows me and mobs to walk in through the roof.

Am I stuck using glass blocks, or is there a way to create the glass roof I desire?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You cannot, [glass panes](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Glass_Pane) are only vertical.

You're gonna have to use regular glass blocks unfortunately.

Comment: Damn...thank you...how do people keep their trapped mobs from jumping out then?

Comment: @Zibbobz normally what i see the glass walls are 2 blocks high, to save on glass panes rather than doing a 3x3 box they make a 2x2 box because when the glass panes join they create a small space in the middle

Answer (score 1):

You need to use glass blocks. Sorry!

To keep mobs in just make 2-block high wall.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately as the other answers say, this isn't possible in vanilla Minecraft. But you can install a mod to achieve this.

[Horizontal Glass Pane mod](https://minecraft.curseforge.com/projects/horizontal-glass-panes)

Answer (score 0):

Well if you have microblock instaled you can make glass covers, they look almost exactly the same. You can place them anyway you want

Answer (score 0):

You can use this fabric mod **https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/horizontal-glass-panes** it is fabric mod it uses fabric API, and there is a forge version **https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/horizontal-panes-forge**

Comment: Hi @THE_WOLF344, is this the same mod mentioned in one of the existing answers already? https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/350611/217524 If so, you can just upvote that one instead of writing another answer.